# Why can't I extend forearm after working out?

Tags: weightlifting

I'm 14, I have a stocky body type and I wanted to get stronger for the summer

To make a long story short 
I was lifting weights on arm day doing reverse dumbar curls for your forearms(50 lbs)

It came to the point where my left arm got so tired they couldn't lift any more well atleast I thought it was just tired

The next day both arms were very sore but after a few hours the left one started to kind of tighten up out of know where. No I can't extend it without an very severe sharp pain

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this pain is centered around the point between your upper and lower arm (opposite of your elbow)? That's the place where the muscle is connected to your bones (tendon). Your tendon(s) might not have been used to this level of stress and as a resultaat they're a bit irritated, thus the sharp pain.

From my own experience I know it is best to keep your arms moving (but no heavy weights until the pain is gone). And an icepack on the place where it hurts also helps tremendously :) I wish you a quick recovery ;)